# ¿Cómo separar un conjunto de archivos en dos grupos en R?

Tags: r, rstudio

Tengo una variable en R que contiene unos archivos y cada archivo contiene una cadena de texto. Tengo que separarlos en dos grupos, en función de si contienen, por ejemplo, ATG o no. O sea, tendría que obtener dos grupos: uno con los archivos que contienen por lo menos una vez el ATG y otro con los archivos sin ATG.
He intentado muchas aproximaciones, todas fallidas, siendo esta la última:

```
with_atg <- list()
n <- 1
for (file in scan_file){
  with_atg[n] <- vapply(file,
                     function(x) {any(ATG %in% x)},
                     logical(length(1)))  
  n <- n + 1 
}
```

También he probado otra versión más sencilla, con mismo resultado:

```
with_atg <- vapply(scan_file, function(x) 
                    {any(ATG %in% x)},
                      logical(length(1)))
```

`scan_file` es la variable con los archivos.
`ATG` sería la variable con lo que tengo que buscar (que puede ser más de una ocurrencia. O sea, que ATG podría ser algo como c("ATG", "TGA", "GAT").
Cuando corro el programa, `with_atg` me sale que todo es FALSE, cosa que sé que no es cierta. No sé ya qué estoy haciendo mal.

Ejemplo de tres de los archivos dentro de scan_file:

```
$`45792NJBAK082`
[1] "CAGCGCGTGCTTGACTAGTTATTTTACACTTGAGGCCGTGCCGTGACAGCCTACTGGTTATTATTGGAAGGGACAAGCGAGATCAGGCGCAGCCTGGTGTCTAGGTTAGAGTTCCAGCGAGGGAGACGCGACGCGGACCAGACCCTCGACAGGTCTATGTAACCCAAAGTGTCCTAATCCTTCAGTTTTGAACATGAAGAAGGTCCTTGCTTACAGGGTCGTAGAAAGGTTGCTTGGCCACGAATACT"

$`48927HSKA`
[1] "TGTGCCAAACACAAAGCGCGCGCGGTAGCTAGTCTGTATCCCGAACAAGCGCGAGACGATAACGAGGCCTGTGTAGCACCACATTGTCGCGT"

$`12NNUANLSO21`
[1] "CCGTCCCGCCACCATACCAGTCTCTCGTTCATACTCACTTCCCCTGAGATTTTTGAATTTTTAGTAAGTTTTATCACAAATACAGTCAGCATTACCGTTAGTTTTTGAGGAGGGCAGGACAACGGTATTACAGGGGACAAGAGGCCTTCCCACATGATCTACTGACCGCTCAGCTAGCTTGCATTAACTACCGTAAAAGAGGCCGGCGAAGCCCGGGCGTTGGGCAACAAGTCTAAGACCGCTCAAACGGCTTACTTAGGAGCTGGGGTGTCCTAGTGGGAGTCTTGAGAAGGGGCGGCAATCTCATGGGTATACGGCTCTAAAACTCTCTTTCGGGGCAGTGGAGGGACAAGGCACAAACCTGTAGTGACCTTTTATACACACATAAGGCGTCTCCGCATACTTTCAGGCCTTGCAACGGTAGGCTTTCATAGGTG"
```

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar un ejemplo de alguno de los archivos?

Comment: Ya está, espero que todo esté claro en mi pregunta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En primer lugar, imagino que cuando haces `any(ATG %in% x)`, `ATG` es una variable, sino tienes un error sintáctico. En todo caso si lo que en  realidad estás haciendo es algo como esto: `any("ATG" %in% x)`, acá es dónde radica tu problema, `x` es la cadena larga, `ATG` solo coincidirá si la misma fuera justamente `ATG`, de ahí que el resultado siempre es `FALSE`. Para buscar parcialmente puedes usar `grepl()` que te retornará un vector lógico, por ejemplo:

```
with_atg <- vapply(scan_file, function(x) {any(grepl("ATG",x))},logical(length(1)))  
with_atg

12NNUANLSO21 45792NJBAK082     48927HSKA 
         TRUE          TRUE         FALSE
```

Si quieres buscar las múltiples combinaciones de los caracteres `ATG` aprovecha los patrones regulares que entiende `grepl()`, de esta forma: `grepl("ATG|GTA|GAT",x)`. Por otro lado, el retorno será siempre un vector con nombres, tal vez una forma mejor sea manejar esto en un `data.frame`, por ejemplo:

```
# Creamos un data.frame para cada archivo con el Flag si es ATG en FALSE
files <- data.frame(name=dir(path = "."), 
                    atg = FALSE,
                    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Establecemos el flag atg en función si el archivo tiene alguna de las convinaciones posibles
files$atg <- sapply(files$name, function(x) {any(grepl("ATG", scan(x, what = "list")))})
files

           name   atg
1  12NNUANLSO21  TRUE
2 45792NJBAK082  TRUE
3     48927HSKA FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

Un enfoque diferente es tokenizar las secuencias y después aplicar un filtrado (subset). La idea es separar a cada secuencia (el contenido del archivo) en grupos de tres caracteres (o dos o cuatro o cuarenta), creando una columna con esa secuencia parcial. Para resolver el problema de la pregunta después se puede aplicar un filtro.

En principio es más complicado que usar una expresión regular, sin embargo creo que tiene una ventaja importante: produce una estructura de datos intermedia en formato tidy muy versatil que podríamos utilizar para otras cosas. Por ejemplo, contar cuantas veces aparece cada secuencia parcial, ver que archivo tiene más variabilidad de secuencias parciales, etc.

En lugar de crear una función ad hoc para tokenizar uso el paquete `tidytext`, que es para análisis de texto. Al fin y al cabo las secuencias de los archivos son cadenas de caracteres.

Asumo que `scan_file` es una lista

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidytext)

scan_file <- list(`45792NJBAK082`= "CAGCGCGTGCTTGACTAGTTATTTTACACTTGAGGCCGTGCCGTGACAGCCTACTGGTTATTATTGGAAGGGACAAGCGAGATCAGGCGCAGCCTGGTGTCTAGGTTAGAGTTCCAGCGAGGGAGACGCGACGCGGACCAGACCCTCGACAGGTCTATGTAACCCAAAGTGTCCTAATCCTTCAGTTTTGAACATGAAGAAGGTCCTTGCTTACAGGGTCGTAGAAAGGTTGCTTGGCCACGAATACT", 
 `48927HSKA` = "TGTGCCAAACACAAAGCGCGCGCGGTAGCTAGTCTGTATCCCGAACAAGCGCGAGACGATAACGAGGCCTGTGTAGCACCACATTGTCGCGT",
 `12NNUANLSO21` = "CCGTCCCGCCACCATACCAGTCTCTCGTTCATACTCACTTCCCCTGAGATTTTTGAATTTTTAGTAAGTTTTATCACAAATACAGTCAGCATTACCGTTAGTTTTTGAGGAGGGCAGGACAACGGTATTACAGGGGACAAGAGGCCTTCCCACATGATCTACTGACCGCTCAGCTAGCTTGCATTAACTACCGTAAAAGAGGCCGGCGAAGCCCGGGCGTTGGGCAACAAGTCTAAGACCGCTCAAACGGCTTACTTAGGAGCTGGGGTGTCCTAGTGGGAGTCTTGAGAAGGGGCGGCAATCTCATGGGTATACGGCTCTAAAACTCTCTTTCGGGGCAGTGGAGGGACAAGGCACAAACCTGTAGTGACCTTTTATACACACATAAGGCGTCTCCGCATACTTTCAGGCCTTGCAACGGTAGGCTTTCATAGGTG")
```

La convierto en un data.frame por filas, paso el nombre de archivo a una columna y creo tríos de caracteres.

```
scan_file %>% 
  map(data.frame, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>%
  bind_rows(.id = "archivo") %>% 
  unnest_tokens(trios,     #Nombre del output
                .x..i..,   #Columna input
                token = "character_shingles",  #para separar por grupos de caracteres 
                n = 3,                         #largo del grupo de caracteres
                lowercase = FALSE,             #preservar mayúsculas en tokenizers
                to_lower=FALSE) ->             #preservar las mayúsculas en unnest_tokens. Ambos son necesarios.
  anibaltroilogardel
```

Finalmente filtro y conservo valores únicos:

```
anibaltroilogardel %>% 
  filter(trios == "ATG") %>% 
  distinct(archivo, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

Lo interesante de la estructura intermedia con estructura de tidydata es que puedo usarla para otras cosas, por ejemplo, para una matriz de ocurrencias:

```
anibaltroilogardel %>% 
  group_by_all() %>% 
  count() %>% 
  spread(trios, n, fill = 0)
```